# Как работает include?

Tags: php, include

Я немного в заблуждении, по пониманию того, как работает функция include в PHP.

Функция include (require) импортирует и выполняет код PHP и в то же время корректно отображает разметку на HTML и получается так, что их можно комбинировать. НО если в исполняющий файл PHP самому добавить разметку HTML, то будет, конечно же, ошибка.

Например, если добавить в основной файл PHP код HTML, то PHP перестаёт корректно работать.

```
<?php
// some code ...
<p>Hello</p>
?>
```

НО если включить разметку HTML, используя функцию include, то ошибки нет. Например:

```
<?php
$title_tag = 'Main Page';
include_once 'pages/home.html';
?>
```

Можете объяснить работу и логику include?

Comment: "*то будет, конечно же, ошибка.*" --- неправда..... точне так: "в исполняющий файл PHP самому добавить **кривую** разметку HTML, то **может быть** некорректная работа"

Comment: Так что утверждение абсолютно ни на чём не основанное. Либо поясняйте что вы делаете и что не так.

Comment: Вы правы. Если добавить текст между тегами, то PHP не показывает ошибку. Но иначе, если добавить просто текст, — то тогда ошибка. Можете объяснить логику? Почему после добавления тегов в код PHP, она *некорректно* работает?

Comment: Вы отредактируйте вопрос, приведите код который пишите. который подключаете, что делаете, когда ошибка возникает **и какая ошибка**.. Переоформите вопрос. Я вот ничего не понимаю что вы делаете, по тексту из комментария не ясно

Comment: Я добавил подробности.

Comment: код html пишут **вне тегов php**. Потому что это html  и ему не место в php....теги пхп только для обработки кода php.....Вот и весь секрет

Comment: Но в файле pages/home.html тоже есть теги HTML. Мои мысли были такие, что команда include просто копирует содержание файла в файл PHP, но получается, что это не так. То есть include не просто копирует содержание файла.

Comment: да, он просто копирует содержимое........но в файле html теги находятся внутри тегов php, что неприемлимо в приницпе... и тут include и require вообще ни при чём. Ошибка будет и без всяких инкллудов если внутри тега php написать  html разметку, а не вне их

Comment: некорректный код:  https://onlinephp.io/c/c548c
   ..............корректный код: https://onlinephp.io/c/804b9

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/0f8a5

Comment: Что вы не поняли из фразы "HTML КОД должен быть **ВНЕ ТЕГОВ PHP**" ? Несколько раз написал это

Comment: Вы тоже говорите, что include копирует содержание. Так после копирования в том файле будет куча тегов HTML, но программа будет правильно работать. Но если РУКАМИ добавить HTML, то будет ошибка.

Мне интересует то, где здесь логика.

Comment: Я кажется понял вопрос :D  .... в общем, ответ таков: *Когда файл включается через include/require - то парсинг в режиме PHP-кода прекращается и переключается в режим HTML в начале указанного файла и продолжается снова в конце* ..... такой вот нюанс .... то есть, можно это читать  так: "автоматически закрывается тег PHP →  копируется содержимое файла → открывается тег PHP после кода этого файла"

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, Алексей Шиманский дал ответ, но я хочу немного уточнить возможно мой ответ покажется понятнее.

Например есть файлы как у Вас:

```
<?php
  $title_tag = 'Main Page';
  include_once 'pages/home.html'; // тут обычный html
?>
```

Ошибка возникает при непосредственном вводе разметки потому, что `PHP` встречает символ `<` который является для него знаком сравнения, а не открытием тега (как Вы могли подумать) и разумеется интерпретатор не может это понять так как это бинарный оператор `a < b`, а левого операнда нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ниже фрагмент исключительно для сравнения поведения анализатора кода:

[image: код]

Когда же `PHP` видит `include_once 'pages/home.html';` он воспринимает это как обычную инструкцию кода, написанную без ошибок и соответственно ни на что не жалуется.

Исследуя исходники я не нашел конкретного места интерпретации `include_once` чтобы понять как происходит момент вставки. Однако  нашел несколько интересных мест типа:

```
    case ZEND_AST_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL:
        switch (ast->attr) {
            case ZEND_INCLUDE_ONCE: FUNC_OP("include_once");
            case ZEND_INCLUDE:      FUNC_OP("include");
            case ZEND_REQUIRE_ONCE: FUNC_OP("require_once");
            case ZEND_REQUIRE:      FUNC_OP("require");
            case ZEND_EVAL:         FUNC_OP("eval");
            EMPTY_SWITCH_DEFAULT_CASE();
        }
        break;
```

Что говорит о схожей природе обработки `eval` и `include_once`.
Далее я запустил такой скрипт:

```
<?php
  echo 'При', include_once 'pages/home.html' , 'вет';
?>
```

В результате увидел ожидаемый вывод:

```
При<html>...</html>1вет
```

Почти то же самое:

```
<?php
   print('Привет' . include_once 'pages/home.html');
?>
```

Вывод:

```
<html>...</html>Привет1
```

**Вывод**: Содержание включаемого файла парсится как и любой `php скрипт` не зависимо от расширения файла, даже для `.txt` и `.mp3` файлов, я проверял. Если там встретятся теги `<?php` и `?>` то заключенный в них код отработает.